# How to block a link that comes from an external script?

Tags: html, hyperlink, external

For a website I am using a countdown script from mycountdown.org.

So I put the script in my html code like this:

```
<body bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<!-- Begin of mycountdown.org script --> 
<div align="center"> 
<script   type="text/javascript" src="http://mycountdown.org/countdown.php?cp3_Hex=0F0200&cp2_Hex=04488C&cp1_Hex=F9F9FF&ham=0&img=&hbg=0&hfg=0&sid=0&fwdt=180&lab=1&text1=Conference&text2=Health &group=Event&countdown=Conference&widget_number=3010&event_time=1359273600&timezone=Asia/Muscat">
</script><a> </div> 
<!-- End of mycountdown.org script -->

</body>
```

It works fine but when I click on the widget it redirect me to the mycountdown.org website. My question is, is there any way I can block that. I understand that the script is external,  hence I dont have access to it. But is there something to do in the html to prevent it.

Thanks,

Comment: Nope, you can't. Maybe you can override the link using an `anchor` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried <a href="http://mywebsite">...script... </a>. It did not work :(